# Django on object save event

Tags: python, django, model

I need a model RiskAssessment that represents

1. name and some other stuff ...
2. a field/link to the RiskLine model for 50 line entries

I need a model RiskLine that represents the (18) coloumns of each line

How can I create a django model that creates the 50 lines in the RiskLine Model on creation of each instance of RiskAssessment and assigns them to my RiskAssessment model?

It is very much like a spreadsheet with always 50 lines and 18 coloumns.

Can I model this in Django at all?

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can.

First create both models, then apply a signal on RiskAssessment `save()`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save

Here is a simple example :

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from yourapp.models import RiskAssessment
from django.dispatch import receiver


class RiskAssessment(models.Model):
    random_property = models.CharField(length=50)

def on_risk_assessment_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']: # just on creation (not update)
        for i in range(50): # create all risk lines (instance is the risk assessment parent)
            rl = RiskLine()
            rl.riskAssessment = instance
            rl.property_a = 'value a'
            rl.save()

post_save.connect(on_risk_assessment_save, sender=RiskAssessment) # links RiskAssessment saving with the function just above ^


class RiskLine(models.Model):
    riskAssessment = models.ForeignKey(RiskAssessment)
    property_a = models.CharField(length=50)
```

Comment: Do post_save and model created belong to the class RiskLine?

Comment: @JRM post edited for clarification. 
And no, they don't belong to RiskLine (as they are on the same indentation level)

Comment: It works nicely. I added a third table for the default content of the lines. On creation I loop over it and read the values.

Comment: Glad I helped! If this answer is the correct one for you, please feel free to click on the "v" left to the answer to accept it and reward me for my modest efforts :-)